# Crontab notify after successful execution?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

- I have a cron job that executes an R script hourly.
- The script checks an online data source that gets updated at an unknown time each day.
- If the data source is not updated, the script exits with an error code.
- If the source is updated, the script runs normally without any error codes.
- After the script completes, I need to begin a manual workflow.
- I would like to receive a notification when the cronjob completes, so I know when to begin my workflow.

Things I have considered doing, but find to be hacky/incorrect:

- Send the Email from within the R script
- Generate error when the Script succeeds

What I want to do:

- Send a customized cron notification email after successful execution
- Something better that I haven't considered yet

Comment: How is sending an email hacky or incorrect? This is a pretty fail-proof method. How would you want to be notified? Like a GUI-popup? Is it a server or a workstation we are talking about?

Comment: Sending an email is fine. The part that feels hacky to me is setting up email notification within R, when cron itself is supposed to be in charge of monitoring its jobs. We are talking about a server.

Comment: Wrap it in a shell script then?

Comment: IMHO it's valid to handle mail notification inside of large, complex scripts. Makes it easier to handle what the mail should contain. You might want to get notified about a warning that occured, even if the job finished cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like the following to the end of your cron job's command line:

```
&& date | sendmail -s "R job completed successfully" you@example.com
```

That will email you an alert on success, and non-zero exit codes will be handled normally by cron.

The `date` is a placeholder for `echo`, `printf`, `cat`, or whatever you want to use to generate the body of the message.

BTW, I used `sendmail` rather than `mail` because the various versions of `sendmail` have more consistent handling of command-line options than the various implementations of `mail` do.

---

Alternatively, just have your R job produce output on stdout.  Unless configured not to do so, cron will email both stdout and stderr from a cron job to the job's owner.

Using `sendmail` explicitly isn't necessary - it just lets you set the subject, recipient address, sender address, add headers, and so on.

`cron` will only send to the job's owner (you) or to whatever email address is set in the MAILTO variable in the crontab.  cron will also set the Subject: to contain `Cron <user@host>`  followed by the command executed by cron.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thanks.